# @NotTransactional alternatives

Tags: spring, junit, mybatis

I'm working on a unit test which commits information through a DAO to a Oracle database, and then retrieves it and checks everything is unchanged.

There are other unit tests in the test class, and at the top of the class I have:

```
@TransactionConfiguration (defaultRollback = true)
```

I'd like to know how I can remove the @NotTransactional. I'm not specifying Transactional on the class, so no tests should be like that by default. Since this is it's own test, I don't know if the @BeforeTransaction (or After) annotations would be correct.

The **biggest problem** is that without the @NotTransactional, it appears as though the unsubscribe() function isn't ran. (the trash flag is unchanged.)

Running the test again, with @rollback=false and @NonTransactional present, I see the trash flag correctly set to true, in the database after the test is finished.

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration (defaultRollback = true)
public class DatabaseTest {

    @Autowired (required = true)
    private FooDao<Foo> fooDao;

    @Autowired (required = true)
    private FooService fooService;

    // other tests here that are marked @Transactional.

    @Test
    @NotTransactional
    public void testDelete() {
        Foo foo = new foo();
        foo.setTrashFlag(false);
        foo.setId(123);

        fooDao.create(foo);

        Foo fooFromDb = fooService.getFromDbById(123);
        assertNotNull(fooFromDb);

        fooService.unsubscribe(123);   // among other things, 
                                       // **sets trash flag to true.**

     // sqlSession.flushStatements();  // doesn't seem to commit the unsubscribe action


        // getFromDbById() returns ONLY Foos with trash set to false, so we expect
        // nothing returned here as we've just set trash to true, using unsubscribe().

        Foo trashedFoo = fooService.getFromDbById(123);   
        assertNull(trashedFoo);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to read any records you've written *within* the same transaction.

Comment: I agree. I'm still unable to determine why it won't do that without @NotTransactional on the test method.

Comment: I admit I never heard of NotTransactional until your question. Can you perhaps show one of your tests and explain what you expect to have happen?  I just put @Transactional on my tests if I need to access child records on Hibernate objects, and that works for me.

Comment: Revised with example code.

Comment: I don't know if it's the "right" way to do such things, but for my tests of this nature, I put `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` on the test.  And if you want to see the data in the database after the test, set `@TransactionConfiguration (defaultRollback = true)` to `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Rollback(false)` isn't always sufficient, it only means the transaction won't be rolled back at the end of test. But it still runs the test in a transaction, which sometimes lead to conflicts with other running transactions.

As Spring suggest, you have two options:

1. Split the test class into two, the transactional tests can be a in test class annotated with `@Transactional`, while the non-transactional test in a test class without transactional annotation.
2. Use method annotations instead of class annotation, annotate each transaction test with `@Transactional`, but remove it from the class scope

Quoting Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html):

> As of Spring 3.0, `@NotTransactional` is deprecated in favor of moving
>   the non-transactional test method to a separate (non-transactional)
>   test class or to a `@BeforeTransaction` or `@AfterTransaction` method. As
>   an alternative to annotating an entire class with `@Transactional`,
>   consider annotating individual methods with `@Transactional`; doing so
>   allows a mix of transactional and non-transactional methods in the
>   same test class without the need for using `@NotTransactional`.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is really on-topic, but I used @NotTransactional for methods that had a transactional base class. Spring says to split the tests in transactional and non-transactional, but I found out that in my case simply adding the following to the method just disabled transactions and let me delete the deprecated annotation:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
```

I thought I just put it out here for people who run in the same thing I did.